# Ruby Check if at least one element from collection meets condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My models have the following relation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :controllers
end

class Controller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`Controller` has a boolean called `is_active`.

I would like to raise an exception if all controller objects which belong to a specific user object are `is_active` false.

Unfortunately i struggle  putting this sentence into code.

```
# if for all controllers is_active false is met, raise exception
# ~>  need to find one controller which is active
array = []
User.find(id).controllers.each do |c|
   array << c.is_active
end
unless array.include?('true') 
 raise ...
end
```

It feels like there is a more `rubisch` way to write this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `is_active` is a database column than you might want to write:

```
Controller.exists?(user_id: id, is_active: true)
```

If is needs to be calculated:

```
User.find(id).controllers.any?(&:is_active)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
user.controllers.any?(&:is_active)
```

would be the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

try  rails way

```
unless User.find(id).controllers.where(is_active: true).any?
  #your code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:controllers).where(id: id, controller: {is_active: true}).count > 0
```